# why does optimism need to derivation from L1 but zk-rollup scheme like polygon zkevm not?

Tags: layer-2, rollups

recently I am reading the optimism docs and the spec named [derivation](https://github.com/ethereum-optimism/optimism/blob/develop/specs/derivation.md) confuse me.
I haven't found it in any docs of zk-rollup projects like zksync, Polygon, or zkevm.

Comment: I have read several articles discussing the differences between zk-rollups and optimistic-rollups, and it appears that I have found the answer:
The key distinction lies in the concept of batch validity. After a rollup, it is crucial to verify the validity of the batch to prevent any malicious actions by the Sequencer.

Comment: In zk-rollups, the batch validity is established through zk-proof. On the other hand, optimistic-rollups take a different approach and do not rely on zk-proof. Instead, they introduce a challenge period where validators can derive data from Layer 1 and independently check the validity of the batch. If a validator discovers that the batch is invalid, they can launch a challenge to rectify the issue.